# Spring boot - Jackson date serialization and deserialization

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

In a spring boot, serialization and deserializations are performed by Jackson. By default, Jackson serialize dates by converting them to GMT timezone and while deserializing, it expects the dates to be in GMT timezone so it will convert them to local timezone. However, in my case we have 2 timezones, EET and EEST. We are not currently in the summer and Jackson is deserializing one date to EET and another to EEST in a same operation and same request. What is the reason for this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up using a unified GMT timezone for all the application. we forced Spring on run to set GMT as application timezone. Code:

```
  @PostConstruct
void started() {
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
}
```

Comment: Cool...its always recommended to keep UTC for database. And just convert in user's timezone after fetching from the server.

Answer (score 1):

Try to deserialize using below by passing timezone.

```
@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", timezone="America/Phoenix")
private Date date;
```

Comment: The problem is that we have 2 timezones in my country so i dont want to update the code twice a year